# ObjC / iOS: NSCFString not NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I'm making a small iOS application which requests a JSON file with ASIHTTPRequest and I want it to be parsed by JSONKit.  I'm using the following code:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
        // yada yada

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/file.json"]; // the file is a valid Json
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:20]; // Response takes too long on local machine
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    responseString = [request responseString]; // request type: ASIREQUEST, responseString is declared as NSString
    NSLog(@"%@ \n", [responseString class]); // NSCFString
        NSDictionary *deserializedData = [responseString objectFromJSONString];
}
```

However, I'm seeing the following exception when the application runs:

```
[7646:207] -[NSCFString objectFromJSONString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdba0000
[7646:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-`[NSCFString objectFromJSONString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdba0000'`
```

What could be causing this exception?  Why is it showing that I'm using an NSCFString here, even though I'm specifying an NSString?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've included `JSONKit.h`, but you forgot to include `JSONKit.m` in the project. It compiles fine, but the implementation isn't there at runtime.

Answer (score 15):

`NSString` is something known as a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html). What this basically means is that when you construct an `NSString` you will get back something that is guaranteed to behave like an `NSString` as defined in its documentation, but could be implemented by some other class. In this case `NSCFString` is the type the system decided to return.

Anything that takes an `NSString` will take anything that is part of that cluster.

From looking at your code, ASI must define `objectFromJSONString` as part of a category on `NSString.` This will work perfectly fine with the clustering system, are you loading a static library that includes ASI? If so you need to add -all_load and -ObjC to your linker flags in order to get categories working from external libraries.

**Edit**:

Based on your comments then your solution is making sure the JSON library is included in your project. I'm assuming the `objectFromJSONString` was copy/pasted from some sample somewhere. It is part of the `JSONKit` library. Make sure both JSONKit.m and JSONKit.h are present in your project.

Update:
JSONKit is included (both .h and .m) but still the same error...
you are right, i just copied it because it seemed to do its job :)

Comment: +1.  Furthermore, I am not aware of a method `-objectFromJSONString` on `NSString`.

Comment: If memory serves, it is part of a library for parsing JSON in Objective-C.

Comment: I already found out, that the linker flags need to be set, but this doesn't solve my problem :/

Comment: Update:
JSONKit is included (both .h and .m) but still the same error...
you are right, i just copied it because it seemed to do its job :)

Comment: Okey guys, thanks for forcing me to include the JSONKit another time ;)
after restarting Xcode and reincluding it worked like a charm!

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem because I enabled ARC and JSonKit doesn't support it after rectifying it worked.

Also when you include JSonKit.h and .m files please make sure you check target box too.

Answer (score 0):

JSONKit declares a category called JSONKitDeserializing on NSString in order to allow you to call objectFromJSONString.  Make sure you've included JSONKit.h in your source file where you are trying to use objectFromJSONString.